# Sampling with replacement question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am selecting three letters at random from the word *onomatopoeia* with replacement.

I want to know how many different three letter combinations can I create?

Comment: does order matter?

Comment: I don't think so. I think the only important thing is you can't repeat the combinations i.e. you can't have ooo and another ooo.

Comment: @David I think they would count as two. The question is about making passwords from 3 letters, so omo and oom would be different passwords.

Comment: i believe it is $n^3$ then, where n is number of unique letters - ignore my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $8$ distinct letters {o,n,m,a,t,p,e,i}. You have $8$ possibilities for the first letter you choose, $8$ for the second and $8$ for the third which gives $$8\times8\times8=8^3=512$$ different words.